# Is there a way to find the uptime of a network card in unix?

Tags: command-line, network-interface, uptime

Some of the information i am requesting can be gleaned from `/var/log/syslog` , e.g:

```
grep wlan /var/log/syslog
```

But the usefulness of that information also depends on how you are network connecting; `dhcp` or `static network connections`, etc.

#### Is there a command line give us the uptime of network card exactly ?

Comment: Do you mean, when was the network card discovered on the PCI/USB Bus, or when the ethernet link came up, or when it first associated with a wifi access point, or when it successfully authenticated to a wifi network, or when it first obtained an IP address? Or when it received or sent its first frame?

Comment: Mr. @StéphaneChazelas: alright.exactly!

Comment: Exactly what? Which one is it?

Comment: I doubt that the network was down between two servers in a period of time (of course when the network goes down, the NIC goes down too). So I want to know when was the last time it came up to make sure if the network went down in the that period of time or not

Answer (score 3):

Use [`rtmon`](http://man.he.net/man8/rtmon) to record network interface changes and then parse its output as needed.

Comment: An example would be nice.